# Why is the "A" in some adverbs silenced?

Tags: pronunciation, stress-reduction

I'm an English learner, and I have had this question troubling me for a really long time.

In the word "magically", we do not pronounce the "a", so it is pronounced just "magicly," like most adverbs having the "-ally."

But in the word *internationally*, we pronounce it as its full form. So is there a rule for this and are there any words which are similar to "internationally"?

Comment: I don't think you'll find any hard and fast rules about the development of pronunciation.

Comment: From the full OED: **magically** - *Brit. /ˈmadʒᵻkli/, U.S. /ˈmædʒək(ə)li/*, **internationally** - *Brit. /ˌɪntəˈnaʃn̩əli/, /ˌɪntəˈnaʃn̩l̩i/, /ˌɪntəˈnaʃənl̩i/, /ˌɪntəˈnaʃ(ə)nəli/, U.S.* I think what that means is both sides of the pond some people articulate the first vowel in both these ***-ally*** suffixes (for those two *specific* words), and some don't.

Comment: I say that 'a' in magically, practically, tactically, etc, so your notion that "we" do not pronounce it is false. Also I have heard people omit it in 'internationally'.

Comment: It's not just the "A"; it's any unstressed vowel, however it's spelled. Unstressed vowels can be spelled with any vowel letter, since letters don't determine sounds, or stress. And it's not just adverbs; it can happen to any word. There are a lot of rules, but one stands out -- in a long word the unstressed vowels will be reduced, centralized, and/or deleted. Listen to the way native speakers pronounce them in natural speech.

Comment: I think I'd be more likely to pronounce the penultimate "a" in "internationally" than in "magically". I think it's to do with stressing and rhythm: "internationally" calls for three stressed/unstressed patterns (trochees) over 6 syllables, although the third pair "ally" is weakened. "magically" fits a stress-unstress-unstress (dactyl). When pronouncing a really long word that we don't say very often, the stress pattern will often be a bit exaggerated or off because stress helps us remember words.

Answer (score 3):

In a comment, John Lawler wrote:

> It's not just the "A"; it's any unstressed vowel, however it's spelled. Unstressed vowels can be spelled with any vowel letter, since letters don't determine sounds, or stress. And it's not just adverbs; it can happen to any word. There are a lot of rules, but one stands out -- in a long word the unstressed vowels will be reduced, centralized, and/or deleted. Listen to the way native speakers pronounce them in natural speech.

Comment: This is a good description of vowel weakening, but it won't explain the OP's issue. The OP's case is one of **compression**. The process is: schwa +  sonorant (in coda) + vowel--> syllabic sonorant + vowel --> sonorant (in onset) + vowel.

Comment: @Araucaria: Your description of the process doesn't account for the distinction between *magically* and *internationally* that the OP asked about.

Comment: @sumelic That's cuz it wasn't an answer! However, OP is wrong in that an /nli/ ending is absolutely perfectly possible there. It may be less pervasive than with 'magically', but there's already a syllabic consonant/potential compression there preceding the /l/ or schwa.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/603199/2085).

Answer (score 1):

#### It's rarely mandatory to pronounce *-ally* as one syllable

> In the word "magically", we do not pronounce the "a"

Not necessarily. As Michael Harvey said in a comment, some speakers do have a four-syllable pronunciation of *magically.* The [Merriam-Webster entry for *magical*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/magically) indicates that the pronunciation of *magically* can be either /ˈmædʒɪkəli/ or /ˈmædʒɪkli/.

> so it is pronounced just "magicly" like most adverbs having the "ally"

This generalization is a bit too broad. *Magically* falls into the more specific class of *-ically* adverbs, which commonly have pronunciations in /ɪkli/. But as you've found,  there are other *-ally* adverbs (such as *internationally*) that are commonly pronounced with /əli/. In fact, I wouldn't say *internationally* is an outlier at all.

I think a reasonable rule to follow would be to use /ɪkli/ in *-ically* adverbs, /fli/ in certain *-fully* adverbs (such as *beautifully* or *awfully*), and /əli/ in any other adverb spelled with a vowel letter followed by *-lly.*

#### Many *-ly* adverbs have *optional* shortened pronunciations

As John Lawler said in his comment, many long words have shortened pronunciations that drop an unstressed vowel. I wrote an [answer to a previous question about the pronunciation of the adverbs "personally" and "finally"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/248662) that has some information about this.

As the comments beneath your question indicate, *internationally* may be shortened by dropping the vowel after /ʃ/. It may even be possible for some speakers to drop the vowel between the /n/ and /l/, even if that pronunciation is not listed in dictionaries.

But these kinds of optional shortenings are often variable and difficult to perceive or precisely describe, and so for a non-native speaker, it may not be very effective to try to reproduce these pronunciations. So I won't try to give a rule about where or when those kinds of reduced pronunciations are likely to occur.

Comment: *principally*, *humbly*, etc

Comment: @Araucaria: "humbly" is not spelled with a vowel letter + *-lly*. "Principally" is missed by the rule that I suggested, but I didn't expect it to have perfect coverage. I wouldn't recommend aiming for /pl/ in "municipally", so I don't think I could easily modify the rule to include *principally*

Comment: It's the same loss of a schwa before an /l/ at the end of an -*ly* adverb. Spelling's not the issue here.

Comment: @Araucaria: I disagree. For one thing, the original poster is a learner who phrased the question in terms of "not pronounc[ing] the 'a'" in *magically.* I don't think words that are spelled with a *-bly* are likely to give as much trouble for somebody in this situation. And setting that aside, I think that many *-bly* adverbs simply don't have any commonly used alternative form pronounced with /bəli/, so I don't think they should be explained as just resulting from the same process as optionally compressed variants of words containing the suffix *-al* followed by *-ly.*

Comment: @Araucaria: For comparison, adjectives ending in *-ble* and *-al* often correspond to *-ity* nouns with non-rhyming pronunciations (for example, *invisible* goes to *invisibility* but *legal* goes to *legality*) so I don't see why it would be implausible that they might likewise correspond to *-ly* adverbs with (potentially) different pronunciations.

Comment: But they do indeed have a commonly used alternative form pronounced with /bəli/. Check in LPD or similar. And it's exactly the same process. Whether you want to cover it or not here is another matter.

Comment: @Araucaria: Unfortunately, I don't own the LPD. Does it show /bəli/ pronunciations for all words ending in *-bly,* including ones with unstressed *-able* or *-ible* like *invisibly* or *agreeably,* or only for ones like *humble* and *stable,* where there is only one syllable before the /b/? While there is variation in the pronunciation of some adverbs derived from adjectives spelled with *-le* (perhaps more than I thought), I do think that there is a real difference in frequency between the use of /bəli/ for *-bly* and /əli/ for *-ally.*

Comment: @Araucaria: Anyway, if you know a better rule unrelated to the spelling for when we tend to see /əli/ vs. /li/, I'd be happy to know of it. I started to write a section about consonant clusters, but I stopped because there's so many possible cases to cover, and even phonotactically "impossible" clusters are probably possible as the output of fast speech compression.

Comment: I really think that I'm less likely to use /bli/ in *globally* than in *nobly,* and that I'm less likely to use /tli/ in *mentally* than in *gently.* I could be imagining that, or it might all be explained by some other factor like relative frequencies of the words, but I don't see why there couldn't be lexicalized differences in this area.