# Why is the pronunciation of the word "definitely" often omits the syllable "nite"?

Tags: pronunciation

I was listening to the broadcasting of esport games(league of legends).

As a non-native speaker, I found out that most of the time both the play-by-play caster and colored caster tend to ignore the sound of "nite" in "definitely".

From \ˈde-fə-nit-lē, to \ˈde-fən.-lē.

The syllable length between the two pronunciation is slightly different, if I had heard it correctly.

Why is the "nit" part being omitted? It sounded very unnatural.

Comment: Omitting the syllable _nite_ would give ‘defily’ /ˡdefəli/, which I don’t recall hearing. Reducing the very common variant [ˡdefnətli] to just [ˡdefn̩ᵗli] or even [ˡdefn̩li], however, sounds quite normal and commonplace to me. It’s really just letting the /ə/ be swallowed by the /n/ and then reducing /ntl/ to /nl/, which isn’t really that extreme.

Comment: It seems to me that one is more likely to hear the first "i" omitted than any other part of the word.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet

It took me a while, but combining your comments and a native speaker friend, I finally understand the reasoning behind all the omitting syllables.

Thank you!

Comment: @HotLicks Thank you, too! I can only mention one ppl in one comment, sorry for that!

Answer (score 0):

The phonetician Jack Windsor Lewis has a web page about pronunciations like this: "[How English is Really Pronounced](http://www.yek.me.uk/wfesttxt.html)". I quoted it in my answers to two related questions, "[Is it common to pronounce 'only' as 'own-knee'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/241407/is-it-common-to-pronounce-only-as-own-knee)" and [Pronunciation of "Personally" and "Finally"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/248662/pronunciation-of-personally-and-finally?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Here is the part that I think is relevant to this particular question:

> 8. Longer adverbs ending with *-ly* are particularly prone to reduction in unselfconscious speech very widely receiving a syllable fewer than is so often indicated in dictionaries. Among examples of this are *previously, seriously, immediately* and *invariably* which generally lack any sound corresponding to the internal *i* of their spelling.

Comment: I imagine Windsor Lewis must be referring to AmE in his §8 here; I’ve certainly never heard a BrE speaker pronounce _immediately_ with “any sound corresponding to the internal _i_”, since the internal _i_ quite consistently palatalises and affricates the preceding /d/ in all but very careful speech. The **first** _i_ can easily be elided, as can the /ə/, the /t/, and the vowel quality of the internal /i/ – but not its effect on the /d/. You can chop it down to /ˈmiːʤli/, but not to /ˈmiːdli/ (or even the much less reduced /ɪˈmiːdətli/).

Comment: It took me a while, but combining your comments, the link from Dr. Jack Windsor Lewis, and a native speaker friend, I finally understand the reasoning behind all the omitting syllables. Thank you!